# Base de datos remota en aplicación de escritorio JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, hosting, host

he estado desarrollando una aplicación de escritorio, he creado su base de datos de manera local en MySqlWorkbench, pero quiero visualizar la información  de la base de datos de manera remota desde cualquier equipo que tenga mi aplicación, de lo que he investigado se que existe un host gratuito que otorga un servidor, usuario y password (Free MySQL Hosting) la cuestión es que estoy buscando lo mismo pero con mayor velocidad y seguridad, así sea de pago.

Agradeceria una respuesta.

Comment: ¿Cuánto es mayor velocidad? ¿Qué es para ti más seguro?

Comment: Si no especificas cuántos recursos necesita tu aplicación por usuario/sesión/transacción no podremos ayudarte. Prueba con un hosting que te permita crecer, comienza con el mas barato y ve incrementando según lo necesites.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! NO lo hagas. nunca expongas tu base de datos al exterior. En su defecto, debes crear una api que acceda a la misma y te permita conectarte remotamente desde clientes. ah. Y en tu pregunta, nombraste dos IDE. En la ide, solo trabajas.. tu programa es en java y la db en mysql... las IDE, no aportan al problema...

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.